# C# accessing camera

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to access the settings of a camera, With user and pass:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace confsiera1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/login?user=userlogin&password=pass";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetHtpp();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void GetHtpp() 
        {
            WebRequest oRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse oResponse = oRequest.GetResponse();

            Console.Write(oResponse);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

currently I'm having this issue:

```
System.Net.WebException: 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

What I am trying to do is access a camera, I have the IP address, user and password.

after accessing the login, I must try to configure it.

Comment: can you do it from a browser on the same machine you are running the code?

Comment: I fixed it, the error was on ip.. thanks about your time